# XAML ContentControl not changing visibility

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatrigger

I have a little problem with my code. I have a content control that I want to switch the visibility on, based on a value of a property.

I have a toggle button that changes the value of the property **IsListView** and the icon without a problem.

```xml
 <ToggleButton Width="26" Height="26" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding IsListView}" Command="{Binding SetItemsViewStyle}" Margin="0,0,5,0">
      <ToggleButton.Style>
          <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MahApps.Styles.Button.Circle}">
             <Setter Property="Content" Value="{iconPacks:BootstrapIcons List, Width=12, Height=12}" />
             <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Switch to list display"/>
             <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                   <Setter Property="Content" Value="{iconPacks:Material Apps, Width=12, Height=12}" />
                   <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Switch to tile display"/>
                </Trigger>
             </Style.Triggers>
         </Style>
      </ToggleButton.Style>
</ToggleButton>
```

Then I have a style for the content control that I would like to hide or display depending on the value of the `IsListView` property:

```xml
<Style x:Key="ListViewStyle" TargetType="ContentControl">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsListView}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            <Setter Property="Content">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="0,31,0,0" >
                        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}"/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The ContentControl is pretty much empty:

```xml
<ContentControl Style="{StaticResource ListViewStyle}">
</ContentControl>
```

The contents are displayed correctly when the screen is initialized (the IsListView is initialized to **true**), but the ContentControl does not dissapear when I click the toggle button. The code behind is executed, including fetching data from the data store, but the screen is not refreshed it seems to me.

What am I missing?

Comment: Show the implementation of the type contained in the DataContext.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found out what was the problem. I should have mentioned in my question that I am using ReactiveUI.

I had a property **IsListView** that was defined like this:

```cs
public bool IsListView { get; set; }
```

It has to be defined like this to ensure that the events are propagated to the view.

```
private bool _isListView;

public bool IsListView
{
    get { return _isListView; }
    set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _isListView, value); }
}
```

Now the controls hide and show as per my requirement.